# Rydarab package and Arabic Typing on overleaf

Tags: packages, languages, arabic, arabtex

Arabic mathematical document containing Arabic symbolic formulas composed with specific symbols in a writing running from right to left according to the Arabic writing.

I try to write using this [RyDarab Package](http://www.ucam.ac.ma/fssm/rydarab/) but I can't do anything.

> How could I import the package to overleaf site and go on?

> What is the specific file should I upload to the site to import the package?

Comment: you need to download the rydarab.rar archive from there then unpack it (you can use winzip7 on windows or unrar in linux or an online tool such as https://www.ezyzip.com/open-extract-rar-file-online.html  but there are 75 files in the archive including font sources and latex support files and documentation, it would be easier to use locally than use on overleaf I suspect. I haven't actually tried to use it, just looked at the file list in the archive using the online tool above (which I just found by google, not anything I have used before)

Comment: Because there many files, I don't know which one should I upload!

Comment: you'd need all the tex files *.sty .tex .def .fd and all the fonts, at least. so basically everything other than the documentation